# TRY_PARSE but faster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-conversion

What would be the quickest way of transforming a large number (almost 100) of nvarchar columns to floats?

At the moment I have a bunch of TRY_PARSE(column-name AS FLOAT) statements, one per column.

Where a column does not parse to float, I want NULL. No error notifications, no extra intelligence.

Is there a quicker way? If so, what would it be?

SQL Server 2012

Comment: I doubt the number of columns is going to be the problem, it's going to be the number of rows.

Comment: You could write your own version of TRY_PARSE but it would be slower. Is this process actually slow or are you embarking on premature optimization? Also, be careful using FLOAT as it is not a precise datatype.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` should be faster...

Comment: @Shnugo why do you think that? I've made a quick test (try_cast vs try_parse on 10000 strings) and the execution plan was exactly the same.

Comment: @Shnugo according to this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3018/performance-comparison-of-the-sql-server-parse-cast-convert-and-tryparse-trycast-tryconvert-functions/  try_cast() and try_convert() will outperform try_parse().  However, there is no consistent pattern of try_cast() over try_convert()

Comment: I agree with@Shnugo here, after a test. i'll post some findings.

Comment: @ZoharPeled See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a short test to show the performance difference between `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CAST`

My result

- `TRY_CAST` 327 ms
- `TRY_PARSE` 17784 ms

That means, that `TRY_CAST` is about 50 times faster than `TRY_PARSE` (btw: `TRY_CONVERT` is almost the same as `TRY_CAST` in performance).

Try it out and post your results ;-)

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeFloatAsString VARCHAR(100),fl2 VARCHAR(100),fl3 VARCHAR(100),fl4 VARCHAR(100),fl5 VARCHAR(100),fl6 VARCHAR(100),fl7 VARCHAR(100),fl8 VARCHAR(100),fl9 VARCHAR(100),fl10 VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @i INT=0;
WHILE @i<100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND(),RAND());
    SET @i+=1;
END

DECLARE @d DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT TRY_CAST(SomeFloatAsString AS FLOAT) fl1
      ,TRY_CAST(fl2 AS FLOAT) fl2
      ,TRY_CAST(fl3 AS FLOAT) fl3
      ,TRY_CAST(fl4 AS FLOAT) fl4
      ,TRY_CAST(fl5 AS FLOAT) fl5
      ,TRY_CAST(fl6 AS FLOAT) fl6
      ,TRY_CAST(fl7 AS FLOAT) fl7
      ,TRY_CAST(fl8 AS FLOAT) fl8
      ,TRY_CAST(fl9 AS FLOAT) fl9
      ,TRY_CAST(fl10 AS FLOAT)fl10
INTO #tmp1
FROM @tbl

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME())


DECLARE @d2 DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT TRY_PARSE(SomeFloatAsString AS FLOAT) fl1
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl2 AS FLOAT) fl2 
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl3 AS FLOAT) fl3
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl4 AS FLOAT) fl4
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl5 AS FLOAT) fl5
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl6 AS FLOAT) fl6
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl7 AS FLOAT) fl7
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl8 AS FLOAT) fl8
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl9 AS FLOAT) fl9
      ,TRY_PARSE(fl10 AS FLOAT)fl10
INTO #tmp2
FROM @tbl

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d2,SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

Comment: Congrats on 50K.   I missed the the big day.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thx, You are coming close ;-)

Comment: I'm more of a try_convert() girl... with your example, try_convert() consistently outperforms try_cast().   I can offer no reason why  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Just did the test myself and got ~17200 (TRY_PARSE), 313 (TRY_CONVERT) and 282 (TRY_CAST). I think, that cast and convert are roughly the same, while parse is far off...

Comment: I tried this on a small sample data first and the results were very promising. TRY_CAST: 7 seconds. TRY_PARSE: I waited 3m17s then killed it.

Comment: @PiotrL *50 times faster* would be 7x50=350 seconds ~ 5.8 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the general answer is that TRY_PARSE can't be replaced by TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT in cases where the user requires the field parsed with a particular culture.

If you're doing simple, straightforward conversions like '... AS INT' then use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT. If you require a translation with a culture, you'll have to stick with TRY_PARSE.

Answer (score 1):

Shnugo made the comment that `TRY_CAST` should be faster, so I thought what better way than to test, and from the "quick" test I did I do agree.

Firstly, a short set up to create some data:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
CREATE TABLE TallyTable (I int);
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3)
INSERT INTO dbo.TallyTable (I)
SELECT I
FROM Tally;

SELECT @SQL =
       N'CREATE TABLE SampleTable (' + 
       STUFF((SELECT TOP 100
                     N',' + NCHAR(10) + 
                     N'    ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'Col',T.I)) + N' varchar(10)'
              FROM TallyTable T
              FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'') + NCHAR(10) + N');';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
SELECT @SQL =
      N'INSERT INTO SampleTable' + NCHAR(10) + 
      N'VALUES(' + STUFF((SELECT TOP 100 ',0'
                          FROM TallyTable T
                          FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'') + N');';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

That creates a table, with 100 columns, with the value "0". Now, if we try `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_PARSE`:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

PRINT 'TRY_PARSE';

SELECT TRY_PARSE(Col1 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col2 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col3 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col4 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col5 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col6 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col7 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col8 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col9 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col10 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col11 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col12 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col13 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col14 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col15 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col16 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col17 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col18 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col19 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col20 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col21 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col22 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col23 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col24 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col25 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col26 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col27 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col28 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col29 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col30 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col31 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col32 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col33 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col34 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col35 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col36 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col37 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col38 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col39 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col40 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col41 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col42 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col43 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col44 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col45 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col46 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col47 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col48 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col49 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col50 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col51 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col52 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col53 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col54 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col55 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col56 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col57 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col58 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col59 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col60 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col61 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col62 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col63 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col64 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col65 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col66 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col67 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col68 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col69 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col70 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col71 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col72 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col73 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col74 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col75 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col76 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col77 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col78 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col79 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col80 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col81 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col82 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col83 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col84 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col85 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col86 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col87 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col88 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col89 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col90 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col91 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col92 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col93 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col94 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col95 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col96 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col97 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col98 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col99 AS float),
       TRY_PARSE(Col100 AS float)
FROM dbo.SampleTable;

PRINT 'TRY_CAST';

SELECT TRY_CAST(Col1 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col2 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col3 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col4 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col5 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col6 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col7 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col8 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col9 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col10 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col11 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col12 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col13 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col14 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col15 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col16 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col17 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col18 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col19 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col20 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col21 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col22 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col23 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col24 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col25 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col26 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col27 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col28 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col29 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col30 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col31 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col32 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col33 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col34 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col35 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col36 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col37 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col38 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col39 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col40 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col41 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col42 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col43 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col44 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col45 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col46 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col47 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col48 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col49 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col50 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col51 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col52 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col53 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col54 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col55 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col56 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col57 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col58 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col59 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col60 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col61 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col62 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col63 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col64 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col65 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col66 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col67 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col68 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col69 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col70 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col71 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col72 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col73 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col74 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col75 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col76 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col77 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col78 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col79 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col80 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col81 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col82 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col83 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col84 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col85 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col86 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col87 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col88 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col89 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col90 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col91 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col92 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col93 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col94 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col95 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col96 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col97 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col98 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col99 AS float),
       TRY_CAST(Col100 AS float)
FROM dbo.SampleTable;

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

The results of the above are marginal, but it still shows:

```
TRY_PARSE

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 4 ms.
TRY_CAST

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

That's a 4ms different with 1 row of 100 columns. Let's up the volume then (this'll take awhile to run):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @SQL =
      N'INSERT INTO SampleTable' + NCHAR(10) + 
      N'VALUES' +STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) +
      N'       (' + STUFF((SELECT TOP 100 ',0'
                                              FROM TallyTable T
                                              FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'') + N')'
                        FROM TallyTable T
                        FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'') + N';';

SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
--Now we have 5001 rows
```

Now we have 5,001 rows, and 100 columns. Now, if we run the above again...

```
TRY_PARSE

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(5001 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 14672 ms,  elapsed time = 18690 ms.
TRY_CAST

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(5001 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 671 ms.
```

A staggering difference of 18019ms (that's 18 seconds, or almost 28 times faster!).

So, the answer is, use `TRY_CAST` (or `TRY_CONVERT`, which I'm sure will be as fast).

```
--cleanup
DROP TABLE dbo.TallyTable;
DROP TABLE SampleTable;
```

Comment: My test (10 columns, 100.000 rows) came up with 50 times faster ;-)

Comment: Yeah, looks like `TRY_PARSE` scales poorly @Shnugo :)